# Swagger-1.2 : How to display n-nested JSON objects in Model Schema

Tags: object, swagger

I'm using **Swagger 1.2** and having a hard time trying to model JSON nested objects, I'd like the Model Schema to display just like in the Swagger online demo Pet store POST/pet (Example Value). For example, my object is:

```
{
   "parent" : {
      "child_1" : {
          "child_2a" : "string",
          "child_2b" : {
              "child_3a" : "string",
              "child_3b" : ["string"]
          }
       }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a more than 1 level JSON. In my `parameter` array, I have something like this:

```
....
stuff here
.....
api: [
{
            "path": "/api/foo/bar",
            "operations": [
                {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "summary": "a job",
                    "consumes": ["application/json"],
                    "authorizations": {},
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "body",
                            "required": true,
                            "type" : "Parent",
                            "description": "some description",
                            "paramType": "body"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "fooz",
                            "description": "some description",
                            "required": false,
                            "type": "string",
                            "paramType": "query"
                        }
                    ],
                    ...... 
                    ........
        }
],
"models" : {
    "Parent": {
            "id": "Parent",
            "required": ["parent"],
            "properties": {
              "parent": {
                "$ref": "Child1"
              }
            }
        },
        "Child1": {
            "id": "Child1",
            "required" : ["child_1"],
            "properties": {
              "child_1": {
                "$ref": "Child2"
              }
            }
        },

        "Child2" : {
            "id"  : "Child2",
            "required" : ["child_2a", "child_2b"],
            "properties" : {
                "child_2a" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                "child_2b" : {
                    "$ref" : "Child3"
                }

            }
        },
        "Child3" : {
          "id"  : "Child2",
            "required" : ["child_3a", "child_3b"],
            "properties" : {
                "child_3a" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                "child_3b" : {
                    "type" : "array",
                    "items": {
                       "type": "string"
                    }
                }
        }

}
```

But the Model Schema display is :

```
{
   "parent" : "Child1"
}
```

I probably did something incorrect ? How do I get it to display entire nested object in the Model Schema ? Just like the Swagger demo pet store POST/Pet Example Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger 1.2 requires the entire model definition to be flat--meaning, you cannot have nested, complex objects, only primitives and references to other complex objects.

As of swagger 2.0, you can now have inline, nested or anonymous objects.

So the short answer is, you cannot model what you are describing in 1.2.  If you can, please consider updating your libraries to use swagger 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.